# WordPress update_user_meta on form submit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a simple form and I want to edit a user meta field on submit. I'm not good with php, but I found some sample code which I thought might be useful. However, once the form is submitted, the user meta field won't update.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_meta_value_val', $_POST['value'] );
} ?>

<form method="POST" action="" id="val_edit">
    <input type="text" value="44" name="value">
    <button value="done" type="submit" form="val_edit">invia</button
</form>
```

thanks